# How do I get my javascript to combine three colors?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First, I completely understand if no one answers this long-winded question. I am not sure how far off base my project is. I am trying to build a program that changes the color of a div and I am new to javascript. I borrowed some code from a similar program but I am failing at formatting it to work for my project.

I've tried moving my javascript around and I've had some success but I am really struggling to learn what I am doing wrong.

```
//js start

var showButton = document.querySelector("#show");
var hideButton = document.querySelector("#hide");

colorBar.style.backgroundColor = "red";

showButton.addEventListener("click", showDiv, false);
hideButton.addEventListener("click", hideDiv, false);


function showDiv(e) {
    colorBar.style.display = "block";
}

function hideDiv(e) {
    colorBar.style.display = "none";
}


var showButton = document.querySelector("#show");
showButton.addEventListener("click", showColorHandler, false);


function showColorHandler(e) {
    var r = parseInt("55");
    var g = parseInt("11");
    var b = parseInt("99");

    container.style.backgroundColor  = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";            
}


container.style.backgroundColor = "burlywood";

var showButton = document.querySelector("#show");
var clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear");

showButton.addEventListener("click", showColorHandler, false);
clearButton.addEventListener("click", clearColorHandler, false);

function showColorHandler(e) {
    var r = parseInt("55");
    var g = parseInt("11");
    var b = parseInt("99");

    colorBar.style.backgroundColor  = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";         
}

function clearColorHandler(e) {
    clear();
}

function clear() {
    colorBar.style.backgroundColor = "OldLace";
}

var input = document.querySelector("#input");
var button = document.querySelector("#clicker");

button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler(e) {
    var n = parseInt( input.value );

    // validate the input value
    if ( validate(n)){
        output.innerHTML = "you entered " + n;
    }
    else {
        alert("You must enter a number from 1 to 10!");
    }
}

function validate(n) {
    if ( n < 1 || n > 10) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//js end




//html start


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Color sampler</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorStyles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p><strong>Enter a number from 0 to 255:</strong></p>
         <div class = inputArea> <p>Red</p>
        <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="3" size="5" value="55" align="right">
        </div>

        <div class = inputArea>
        <p>Green</p>
        <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="3" size="5" value="11" align="right">
        </div>

        <div class = inputArea>
          <p>Blue</p>
        <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="3" size="5" value="99" align="right">
        </div><br>

        <div id="colorBar"></div>

        <div>
        <button id="show">Show me the color!</button>
        <button id="hide">Hide the color</button><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
        <button id="clear">Reset all</button><br>    
        </div>

     </div>   

      <script src="colorChange.js"></script>


</body>
</html>

//html end
```

I just want to be able to put the number between 0 and 255 into the three text boxes and have the color bar change color after the show color button is clicked.

Comment: Your code is not particularly wrong, except it is way to messy. You declare some variables, don't declare others; you bind several listeners to the same elements; you have multiple elements with the same ID, which is a big no-no; quote some classes, not others. But the reason it doesn't work is because you're looking for an element `#clicker`, which doesn't exist. My suggestion: stop "moving code around", calm down, and start writing code in an organised way, so that you know where everything is; and learn to use the Developer Tools, so that when things go wrong you can see where it happened.

Comment: The HTML is at the bottom. Thank you, I know its a mess. I commented out the "clicker" and am now looking at where I bonded listeners to the same elements. I really appreciate you looking at this

Comment: For example, I count no less than three `var showButton = ...`, followed by `showButton.addEventListener("click"...`. All of your RGB inputs have `id="input"`. And while `<div class = inputArea>` is not an error, as such, because HTML does allow it, but it is kind of bad style not to quote attributes, unless you're being Google and conserving every byte. You have two `showColorHandler` functions (which probably shouldn't be there in the first place). And RGB values should be from 0 to 255, not from 1 to 10.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think that adding it more than once was a problem.. I did it as a kind of a catch-all (I didn't know exactly where to put some things). Thanks for explaining that to me.

Comment: Defining a function more than once is not a problem (as later definitions overwrite the earlier ones), except that it confuses whoever is trying to debug the code (usually yourself). But _binding_ a function more than once, with `addEventListener`, will make it execute several times for each event, which is typically not what you want. If you have code you don't want to use but are not ready to delete, comment it out.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I appreciate the advice, extremely helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a little demo here for you.

The way this demo works is I have three inputs: one for Red, one for Blue, and one for Green. I have set these inputs to start at 0 using the `value` HTML attribute. I have event listeners in my JavaScript waiting for these inputs to be changed by the user. Once one of them is changed, I trigger a function which takes the current values of the inputs and creates an "rgb()" string out of them. It then applies this string to the div using `styles.backgroundColor =`. This way, a user can manipulate the color of the div by changing the three inputs.

[Here's a silly little website](https://compositor.jaredgorski6.now.sh/) I made that does something like this, just for fun.

Run this demo to try it out:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("div");
const rInput = document.getElementById("r");
const gInput = document.getElementById("g");
const bInput = document.getElementById("b");

document.getElementById("r").addEventListener('change', () => {
  handleInputs();
});
document.getElementById("g").addEventListener('change', () => {
  handleInputs();
});
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener('change', () => {
  handleInputs();
});

function handleInputs() {
  const rVal = rInput.value;
  const gVal = gInput.value;
  const bVal = bInput.value;
  
  const rgbVal = `rgb(${rVal},${gVal},${bVal})`;
  
  div.style.backgroundColor = rgbVal;
}
```

```html
<input id="r" placeholder="R" type="number" value=0 min="0" max="255" step="1"></input>
<input id="g" placeholder="G" type="number" value=0 min="0" max="255" step="1"></input>
<input id="b" placeholder="B" type="number" value=0 min="0" max="255" step="1"></input>
<div id="div" style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
```

Perhaps seeing this working example will get your wheels turning regarding how to apply this type of idea to your code.

Comment: Wow, this is so much simpler than the ideas I was fumbling around with! Thanks a lot.